# Activity Result Api при 2 callback

Tags: android

я пытаюсь из старого OnActivityResult сделать миграцию в новую версию свой код, то есть у меня есть ImageView при клике на него открывается галерея , далее при выборе фото , дальше возникает св-во обрезки Фото. Все это я хочу осуществить с помощью Activity Result Api, я пробовал 2 contracta registr создавать, но в таком случае как быть  в setOnclickListener он один не может обрабатывать 2 регистра контракта я вообще не могу догнать , пробовал внутри registr contract , написать эти 2 св-во не выходит как быть??

вот мой код при старом activity Result Deprecated

```
 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) { /// неед
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            if (requestCode == REQUEST_GALLERY) {
                data?.data.let {
                    if (it != null) {
                        imageUri = it  (доступ к галерее)
                        cropImage(it) }
                }

            } else if (requestCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {  (обрезает фото и загружает в Imageview)
                val resultUri = data?.let {
                    UCrop.getOutput(it) }
                binding.image.loadUrl(resultUri.toString())
            }
        } else {
            toastMessage(requireContext(), getString(R.string.fail_download_image))
        }
    }

    private fun openGallery() {    /// галлерея
        val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY)
```

тут внутри контракта пытаюсь 2 callbacka вызвать не выходит

```
 private val resultContract = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result: ActivityResult? ->
        if (result?.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
            result.data?.data.let {
                if (it != null) {
                    imageUri = it
                    cropImage(it) }
                }

        } else if (result?.resultCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP){
            val resultUri = result.data?.let {
                UCrop.getOutput(it)
            }
            binding.image.loadUrl(resultUri.toString())
        }
    }
```

а тут 2 registr contract

```
private val resultContractTwo = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result: ActivityResult? ->
        if (result?.resultCode == UCrop.REQUEST_CROP) {
            val resultUri = result.data?.let { UCrop.getOutput(it) }
            binding.image.loadUrl(resultUri.toString())
        }
    }


    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        shapeImage()
        setupToolbar()
        setupListeners()
    }
  private fun setupListeners() {
        binding.image.setOnClickListener {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            resultContract.launch(intent)  // тут 2 callback они двоя не вызываться как быть?
            resultContractTwo.launch(intent)
            binding.imageIcon.visibility = View.GONE
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основные моменты:

- на каждый `requestCode` нужно зарегистрировать launcher с колбеком
- каждый `startActivityForResult()` заменяем на `launch()` соответствующего launcher
- из `onActivityResult` берём ветки `requestCode` и переносим их в соответствующие колбеки - то есть не в один колбек всё запихиваем, а каждый `requestCode` обрабатывается своим колбеком

```kotlin
private val imageCropLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result: ActivityResult? ->
        if (result?.resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK ) {
            val resultUri = result.data?.let {
                UCrop.getOutput(it)
            }
            binding.image.loadUrl(resultUri.toString())
        } else {
            toastMessage(requireContext(), getString(R.string.fail_download_image))
        }
    }

private val imagePickLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()){ result: ActivityResult? ->
        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            data?.data.let {
                if (it != null) {
                    imageUri = it  (доступ к галерее)
                    cropImage(it) }
            }
        } else {
            toastMessage(requireContext(), getString(R.string.fail_download_image))
        }
    }
```

Лончеры с колбеками зарегистрированы - осталось вызвать, меняем везде:
`startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_GALLERY)` на `imagePickLauncher.launch(intent)`
`startActivityForResult(intent, UCrop.REQUEST_CROP)` на `imageCropLauncher.launch(intent)`

Comment: эти 2 callbak внутри одного set.Onclicklistener можно реализовать?   я их внутри одного клика вставляю,  эти 2 callback . тогда галерея открывается,  но картинку приходиться 2 раза нажимать чтобы обрезать. но фото не загружает. при старом методе он загружает

Comment: Зачем? У вас же второе действие должно выполняться по результатам первого и всё это уже было реализовано, насколько я понял - как заменить старый код на новый я описал, остальное можно оставить как было. То есть добавляем лончеры, заменяем `startActivityForResult` на `Launcher.launch()` и удаляем `onActivityResult()` - всё!

Comment: ну не знаю все ровно не срабатывает  я внутри интента, вставляю 'val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)'

Comment: Если до миграции на Activity Result Api работало как надо и вы всё сделали правильно, то должно работать и сейчас. Где-то вы напартачили, но не видя весь связанный код - невозможно сказать где.

Comment: спасибо Вам,  я только уточню у Вас, `val intentOne = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI)
            imagePickLauncher.launch(intentOne)
            imageCropLauncher.launch(intentOne)`  сам интент при запуске в ActivityResultApi так должен выглядеть??

Comment: Он должен выглядеть точно также, как и до миграции. Только нахрена вы его двумя лончерами запускаете? Так у вас запускается выбор или два раза, или результат приходит не туда, куда надо. Для выбора используйте `imagePickLauncher`, для обрезки `imageCropLauncher`